# AngularJS orderBy not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-orderby

i am facing some weird issue in ordeBy, i know this should be very simple but couldn't make out

Please look at a below plunker, where the `orderBy` by `value` not showing correct output, i don't no why :(

[**DEMO PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ClfT3QEbyj9ku0Lf8k7u?p=preview)

Comment: The answer is fairly simple. Objects or objects attributes can't be ordered, you should use array instead

Comment: @maurycy Ohk, thx man (y)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep doing that, you'll have to create a filter for inverted indexes based on the property you want (here the whole object) so that you can retrieve the key and hence the value

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the numbers to strings and make sure the strings are the same length

```
var temp = {"054": "A",
        "244": "B",
        "344": "C"};
```

this works.